# ComposerからLaravelのプロジェクトを立ち上げたい

Tags: php, laravel, vscode, composer

#### 実現したいこと

ComposerからLaravelプロジェクトを立ち上げたい。

#### 前提

Laravelでの開発をしたく、vscodeでの環境構築をしていたのですが、Laravelプロジェクトをターミナルから立ち上げようとすると、以下の問題が発生。

```
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem
```

そのため、以下のサイトを参考に対処。
ファイルはxamppにある「php.inidevelopment」を「php.ini」に名前を変更して内容を変更しました。
https://akizora.tech/laravel-curl-error-3390

再び立ち上げようとすると、以下のエラーが発生。

```
The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not available. If you can not enable the openssl extension, you can disable this error, at your own risk, by setting the 'disable-tls' option to true.
```

こちらのエラーは以下のサイトを参考に対処

https://digirakuda.org/blog/2018/06/04/post-251/

その後にプロジェクトを立ち上げようとすると、プロキシ関係でエラーが発生しました。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Err
  or messages:
  error:エラーコード:SSL routines::certificate verify failed
  Failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy
```

#### 試したこと

以下のサイトを参考にさせていただきました。
プロキシ経由でインターネットを利用していると発生するエラーらしく、対策法が記載されていたので試したところ、うまくいきませんでした。

https://akamist.com/blog/archives/222

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

PHP:8.2.4   Composer:2.5.8
エディタ:vscode

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://qiita.com/asulucky2001/questions/3a130250fb95a156e2d5) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)